# ArcGIS Pro cloned Python environment changes to default

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, installation, geopandas, environment-variable

I have created a clone of the default environment in ArcGIS Pro 2.8, and have installed GeoPandas within it. In ArcGIS Pro Setting I activated the clone environment [toggle radio button) and restarted ArcGIS Pro. However, after the restart, the ArcGIS setting Python shows that the default environment is activated. After the restart instead of the clone environment being activated the default is in fact activated.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Are you sure its 2.8(.0)? This is a known bug in 2.8.1.
https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/arcgis-pro-2-8-1-keeps-changing-python-environment-back-to/m-p/1072838

Comment: as Martan says, this is a problem in 2.8.1. Problem should be fixed in 2.8.2.  For now you could downgrade to 2.8.0.

Comment: @Martan Yes you are right it was 2.8.1 . Thank you guys.